# HTML5 animation and easing

Tags: javascript, html

The following code is my first attempt at any real animation using html5. Let's just say it moves, but it leaves me wanting more, like easing, bounce, or any other nice animation equations. Are there any libraries that assist in doing these nice animations? Can jquery be used somehow?

My code just feels a little too archaic, or maybe that's the state html5 is in right now:

```
function animateImage(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c'), context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    var xpos = 0;
    img.onload = function(){

        if (!img) return;


        var timer = setInterval(function(){
                    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                    context.drawImage(img,xpos,0);

                    xpos = xpos + 20;

            }, 1000/200);

    }

    img.src = 'Cupcake_01.png';
}
```

I should also add that it is very jittery; not smooth at all.

Comment: Demo of code: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jDJN5/ It's a little wile-e-coyote-like. And yes, there are libraries. Raphael.js comes to mind. [EaseJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS). They're not that hard to find. [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/).

Comment: yes I found tween.js. Isn't raphael for svg?

Comment: I'm not too sure. KineticJS looks exactly like what you described, `canvas`-based and HTML5. Only thing I'm not sure about is jQuery support.

Comment: I"m using this library: https://github.com/sole/tween.js/  However, it's slow with larger images. I don't get all the hype with html5, it's not exactly replacing flash in terms of animation.

Comment: Here's an interesting combination of [CoffeeScript, jQuery and KineticJS](http://coffeequery.blogspot.com/2012/04/kineticjs-kaleidoscope-tango.html).

Comment: Yes, apparently KineticJS is extremely fast. It's probably a matter of HTML5 being new and optimizations still to be made. For instance, I'm not sure `canvas` is hardware-accelerated. Have you seen [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/)? Based on webGL, which is really, really cool. Plus [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/), of course.

Comment: In Chrome and Safari you can do this using just CSS: http://www.webkit.org/blog/138/css-animation/

Answer (score 7):

if you want to avoid the overhead of animation libraries (I try to avoid loading libs wherever posible) you should have a look at Robert Penner's easing equations. These are kind of the 'standard' in easing and have been around for about 10 years, most of the js animation libs use them either inherently or are regularly extended to include them here are some refs:

the original, in actionscript:
http://robertpenner.com/easing/easing_demo.html

some refs for javascript:
http://upshots.org/actionscript/jsas-understanding-easing

http://jstween.blogspot.co.uk/